# Fastest way to write a 2d array to file image?

Tags: c, image

I have a simple 2d array, like this:

```
unsigned char myArray[100][100];
```

I don't need any advanced image processing, I only need to write this image (gray levels) in a file (it can be any image formats).

I think I can use the image format: .ppm (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Write_a_PPM_file#C) like this:

```
 (void) fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", dimx, dimy);
  for (j = 0; j < dimy; ++j)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < dimx; ++i)
    {
      static unsigned char color[3];
      color[0] = i % 256;  /* red */
      color[1] = j % 256;  /* green */
      color[2] = (i * j) % 256;  /* blue */
      (void) fwrite(color, 1, 3, fp);
    }
  }
```

I can write the same value for RGB to emulate a gray level image, but is there a better alternative?

Comment: If you only want grayscale, [PGM might be better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Comment: so you have code, can set the same level for R G B. you have a solution. why are you looking for a "better" one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TGA format which is more common than PPM and allows true grayscale images. Saving them is very easy. Prepare an array of 9 elements:

```
uint16 header[9]
```

write into it: 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 8

fwrite those 18 bytes, then your 100x100 array in a single shot. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: if you are using grayscale, you only need 1 channel, therefore only 8 bits per channel is enough. Write a BMP file. The BMP format opens everywhere and the header is very easy to write by yourself. Not everybody opens PPM or PGM.

Hint: Download [010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) (an hexadecimal editor, get the trial) and loads a bitmap on it. You can navigate over the headers of the bitmap. It will speed up the learning about the header. so you can write it by yourself... of course, 1 byte per pixel.

In my sample down here I used C++... but it's easy to convert to C if you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#pragma pack( push, 2 ) // avoid structure padding... I am using Win32 here

struct BITMAPFILEHEADER
{
    unsigned short  bfType;
    unsigned int    bfSize;
    unsigned short  bfReserved1;
    unsigned short  bfReserved2;
    unsigned int    bfOffBits;
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    unsigned int    biSize;
    int             biWidth;
    int             biHeight;
    unsigned short  biPlanes;
    unsigned short  biBitCount;
    unsigned int    biCompression;
    unsigned int    biSizeImage;
    int             biXPelsPerMeter;
    int             biYPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int    biClrUsed;
    unsigned int    biClrImportant;
};

#pragma pack() // avoid structure padding... I am using Win32 here

using namespace std;

void saveBitmap( const string & p_output, int p_width, int p_height )
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;
    memset( &bitmapFileHeader, 0xff, sizeof( BITMAPFILEHEADER ) );
    bitmapFileHeader.bfType = ( 'B' | 'M' << 8 );
    bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof( BITMAPFILEHEADER ) + sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
    bitmapFileHeader.bfSize = bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits + ( p_width + ( p_width % 4 ? ( 4 - p_width % 4 ) : 0 ) ) * p_height; // multiply by 3 if you wanna switch to RGB

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;
    memset( &bitmapInfoHeader, 0, sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER ) );
    bitmapInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
    bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth = p_width;
    bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight = p_height;
    bitmapInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = 8; // this means grayscale, change to 24 if you wanna switch to RGB

    ofstream file( p_output, ios::binary );

    file.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &bitmapFileHeader ), sizeof( bitmapFileHeader ) );
    file.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &bitmapInfoHeader ), sizeof( bitmapInfoHeader ) );

    // bitmaps grayscale must have a table of colors... don't write this table if you want RGB
    unsigned char grayscale[ 4 ];

    for ( int i( 0 ); i < 256; ++i )
    {
        memset( grayscale, i, sizeof( grayscale ) );
        file.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( grayscale ), sizeof( grayscale ) );
    }

    // here we record the pixels... I created a gradient...
    // remember that the pixels ordem is from left to right, "bottom to top"...
    unsigned char pixel[ 1 ]; // do pixel[ 3 ] if you want RGB

    for ( int y( 0 ); y < p_height; ++y )
    {
        for ( int x( 0 ); x < p_width + ( p_width % 4 ? ( 4 - p_width % 4 ) : 0 ); ++x ) // + ( p_width % 4 ? ( 4 - p_width % 4 ) : 0 ) because BMP has a padding of 4 bytes per line
        {
            if ( x > p_width )
            {
                pixel[ 0 ] = 0; // this is just padding
                file.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( pixel ), sizeof( pixel ) );
            }
            else
            {
                pixel[ 0 ] = 255 * ( x * y ) / ( p_width * p_height );
                file.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( pixel ), sizeof( pixel ) );
            }
        }
    }

    file.close( );
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    saveBitmap( "test.bmp", 1000, 1000 );
    return 0;
}
```